# Do I need to download a specific js library to use highcharts-ng directive or is it already embedded in highcharts.js

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angular-ui-bootstrap, highcharts-ng

I am trying to use highcharts with angular. now I wanted to use ready made directive `highcharts-ng` but nothing is showing up. I am suspecting that I need to download/use external library although I see nothing mentioning that. so my question is Do i need to to download an external file/library to use the highcharts-ng directive?

regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the readme of the github everything is explained, including how to add the script from a cdn but you can also download the file that is inside the src folder

https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Comment: thanks! i copied and pasted it in a file and started to use it..didn't work though but that's another story